# What's the proper file format for local data to implement a sync feature with a SQL database server?

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, file-format

This question might be quite dumb, but I couldn't find anything related.

Let's say a user can create and modify a shopping list in an application, that data would be synchronized to the SQL server whenever network is available and vice-versa.

What file format should the local data stored in? Using a local SQL database server won't make much sense for a mobile platform.

Should I store everything into a JSON file locally, or there is a better approach?

Comment: "Using a local SQL database server won't make much sense for a mobile platform." Why not?

Comment: Use whatever file format is most convenient for your application. It will depend on the programming language used, for one.

Comment: @jarlh Because I'm not sure if that's even possible, SQL server doesn't seem available on mobile, and for the library I'm using, there's only a connect method and there isn't serve.

Comment: Aren't you using Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh I do. Postgresql's manual has no mention of serving in mobile platform.

Comment: @jarlh correct me if I am wrong, am I able to connect through localhost directly, without "starting" the server?

Comment: I _guess_ you need a server. I've only run Postgresql on desktop PC.